# How to prevent crash on quest 'Hunting a Witch' / Bathtub scene?

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3

Unfortunately, I can't follow this scene:

After the naked witch leaves the bathtub and dress some clothes and necklaces, the screen freezes immediately. I can hear the begin of a conversation in the background, but the visual game freezes. This will occure again and again at the exactly same position.

Do you know any fix for this specific crash?
(I'm playing with the newest patch 1.05 applied on a Win7 with NVIDIA GTX graphics card).

Comment: Hey PeterCo. Just wanted to remind you that you can mark the answer that helped you as accepted, just in case you might have forgotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same crash and I found that turning off NVIDIA HairWorks and putting your game in full-screen mode resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks! That - and some other comments in other forums - helped me to workaround this crash: I just reduced the graphics quality to the lowest option. Re-Loaded a saving point and Tataaaaa: No more crash in this scene. After the split of Keira and Geralt, I saved the game again, reverted my graphics settings to high and everything is back to normal!

Comment: Nice, good to hear, took me a quite some time to fix it, was very frustrating. Good that you could fix it quickly.

Comment: @PeterCo, if this answer solved the problem, mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue in different way i increase my in game specs and pass it .
I try to lower all graphic option 1st and was crashing over and over again , after i increase graphic specs and pass with no problems .

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to see if your video drivers are up to date.

And if the game was working previously, roll back to a previous patch (no idea how to do this on steam, Gog lets you choose which patches to apply) long enough to get past the cutscene.

Comment: Drivers are up to date "353.06  WHQL" from 2015/05/31. Roll back to a previous patch is a little bit tricky, specially with saved games...

Answer (score 0):

For me getting naked and running the game on lowest settings worked.

Comment: Are you sure, that 'getting naked' not has another intention in this specific scene? .-) SCNR

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you are in full screen mode. Keira Metz seems to like to crash Borderless or Windowed mode.